# Spring framework with Alexa Skill SDK V2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, alexa-skills-kit

I am starting to develop an Alexa App (SDK v2), and I want to host it on my server, instead of using AWS Lambda.

I used to use the Spring Framework in my previous projects, and I have read a lot of examples on the internet on how to use Alexa framework with Spring boot. All those were implemented using the first version of the Alexa API.

Is the case the same if I use the second version? Also, can I use Spring features/tools without Spring boot? (annotations, servlet, containers,etc)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned Spring Framework, I am assuming you are using Alexa Skills Kit SDK for Java V2 (GitHub link here - https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java).

To answer your questions: 
Is the case the same if I use the second version?

**No** - It is not the same if you use the second version, as the first version was kind of using monolithic approach to develop the Lambda function code and in the second version the design is more modular. You'd be working with more classes and implementations with the second version which makes it very easy to scale and maintain.

Also, can I use Spring features/tools without Spring boot? (annotations, servlet, containers,etc)

**Yes**, you can use the spring features by using the xml based implementation of spring if you don't wanna use spring boot

Also, make sure you are using the latest maven repository for ask-sdk which has just launched in November 2018

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.alexa/ask-sdk -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazon.alexa</groupId>
<artifactId>ask-sdk</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```